# Check if a .csv cell is empty

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to add a .csv table into my 2d array, but want to sort out all the empty cells.

This is how my code currently looks:

```
try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(upload.pathName));
        String strLine;

        for (int i = 0; (strLine = reader.readLine()) != null; i++) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(strLine);
            scanner.useDelimiter(";");
            int j = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    if (scanner.next() == null || scanner.next().equals("")) {
                        System.out.println("this cell is empty");
                        j++;
                    } else {
                     array[i][j] = scanner.next();
                     j++;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception abcdefg) {
        //Exception
    }
```

my .csv looks something like this:

```
value1;value2;value3;value5;value6;value7
value8;value9;value10;...
```

Can this line even work?:

```
if (scanner.next() == null || scanner.next().equals(""))
```

And does anybody know why when I use only if(scanner.next() == null) OR if(scanner.next().equals("")) j loops till it has the value 5 and afterwards actiaves Exception abcdefg, but when I use if(scanner.next() == null || scanner.next().equals("")) j only loops till it has the value 3 and then triggers the Exception abcdefg

What am I missing/where lies my mistake and why does it jump into the Exception, even when there are still cells that are not empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if condition is OK, except that you don't want to call `scanner.next()` twice, which will 'eat' some input.

You would want to set the value of `scanner.next()` to a variable and then check the variable value in the if condition:

```
String input = scanner.next(); 
if(input == null || input.equals("")){
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the `scanner.next()` value into a variable like below. Use the variable in the condition. Since you are calling `next()` twice your pointer is moving twice.

```
String value = Scanner.next()
```

Why don't you use something like https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html to read CSV. There are many such libraries available to read CSV files.