# How to create an emtpy cell in csv if data not found

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to scrape some data from a website. It looks like this:
Person 1
    Data 1
    Data 2
    Data 3
    Data 5

Person 2
    Data 2
    Data 3
    Data 7

I would like the output in csv to be like:

```
Person 1    Data 1  Data 2  Data 3  Data 4  Data 5  Data 6  Data 7
            data    data    data            data

Person 2    Data 1  Data 2  Data 3  Data 4  Data 5  Data 6  Data 7
                    data    data                            data
```

However, I don't know how to force data output if data is missing. I know there might be some try, except (maybe).

I'm using python 3.6.7 and selenium. BTW in the above example 'data' is any value found for the Data1-Data7 entries. 
I hope it is clear.

Comment: You can check for an empty cell and if its empty then you can print empty quotations or no data... Refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35962124/check-if-a-csv-cell-is-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35962124/check-if-a-csv-cell-is-empty)

Comment: No. I don't want to scan or check if a cell is empty. I want to create an empty cell if the data doesn't exist

Comment: Ok, seems like you found the solution of your problem... Happy Coding...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all that tried to help me. I found the solution:

```
Data=None
    try:
        Cell=elm.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='whatever_the_class_name'][contains(.,'whatever_data')].text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Data=' '
    line.append(Data)
```

The penultimate line of code is the answer of my question. Well, the simpest things are (sometimes) the hardest ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply check if the data is empty and if it is, replace the empty text with whatever

```
for row in csvreader:
        try:
               #your code for cells which aren't empty
        except:
               #your code for empty cells
```

You can also try something like this
This will fill all empty cells to eqaul 0

```
result.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

EDIT--------

Since there is no code posted with your answer here is a basic example of how you could replace the empty cells

```
for cl in list_of_columns:
  df[cl] = df[cl].replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)
  df[cl] = df[cl].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thank you Julian. Anyway, I wonder (for quite some time now) what the code after "except" should be to leave the cell empty.

Comment: You can do the result.fillna , or perhaps if result = “” { result = “EMPTY”}

Comment: You have not shared any code so I cannot provide you with an example that is tailored to how you have coded the results your getting back

Comment: If you provide code on how you are getting the results I can provide a more direct answer

Comment: Can I email the code to you Julian? This is my email: private_it@mail2techie.com

Comment: Why? Email? Just paste the relevant code into your question. You do not need to paste the entire code. Just the code that grabs the csv data and reads it